# Used to vs present perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, used-to

One of my colleague asked her students to rephrase this sentence:

> We started to write to each other three years ago.

And her answer is:

> We used to write to each other in two years.

I see something wrong in her answer, is it right? Because “used to” is used for an action in the past and it no longer happens. I can rewrite this like that:

> We have written to each other for three years.

Or

> I have been writing to each other for three years.

Comment: You're right. Her answer is nonsense. Your last sentence should read, "***We*** have been writing..."

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope you always help me whenever I get confused in English language.